# Cannot acces linux (server) shared folder via windows

Tags: server, windows-10, minecraft, shared-folders

So i saw multiple of similiar questions but none of them worked. I am using ubuntu 19.10 (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-42-generic x86_64) (server version)
I want to make a mc server that is hosted on a linux machine however i cannot acces the files via windows 10. It says "enter network credentials" but it also says "acces denied" https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdKT0.png
i saw some post where it said to write this :
`sudo -u ubuntuadmin "/minecraft"`
ubuntuadmin (my name)
"minecraft" (folder that i want to share)

However it says : ls: cannot acces '/minecraft' : No such file or directory. Even though the "minecraft" folder is clearly there when i type ls

Oh and just to make sure. Credentials are username and password right?

Thank you to anybody that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file at the bottom

```sh
[PreferedNameForSharedFolderOnNetwork]
path = /path/to/your/folder/to/be/shared
available = yes
valid users = user1 user2 user3
read only = yes
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = no
```

**Note:** above users should be on samba group

#### create / add user for samba

Run the following command to create new samba user or add an existing user to samba and create password for samba.

```sh
sudo smbpasswd -a username
```

Finally, restart samba

```sh
sudo systemctl restart smbd.service
```

From windows enter the valid user you've allowed in samba and samba-password you created.

Comment: When trying to get the path to the folder (meanwhile editing the samba file i cannot type / and instead it types <F2> for me. Also windows told me right now that it cannot acces \\x\y wich wasnt an issue before. Also what do you mean by "Note : above users should be on samba group"? thanks for the help

Comment: update : i dont have idea how. but it works. i just did the same thing like 5 times and it works this time. Thank you for the help (commenting so you dont respond for no reason)

Comment: @Tahmkenchontop every user is a member of some group, for example, `sudo` is a group and administrator accounts are a member of `sudo` group that's why they can access `sudo` command. same thing for this case.. the users you're adding samba config must a samba user, u can achieve this by adding that user to samga group.

Comment: @Tahmkenchontop If you can accept the answer that'd be great :)